# KFold cross validation: shuffle =True vs shuffle=False

Tags: cross-validation, k-fold

Should I set `shuffle=True` in `sklearn.model_selection.KFold` ?

I'm in this situation where I'm trying to evaluate the `cross_val_score` of my model on a given dataset.

if I write

```
cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=X, y=y, cv=KFold(shuffle=False), scoring='r2')
```

I get back:

```
array([0.39577543, 0.38461982, 0.15859382, 0.3412703 , 0.47607428])
```

Instead, by setting

```
cross_val_score(estimator=model, X=X, y=y, cv=KFold(shuffle=True), scoring='r2')
```

I obtain:

```
  array([0.49701477, 0.53682238, 0.56207702, 0.56805794, 0.61073587])
```

So, in light of this, I want to understand if setting `shuffle = True` in `KFold` may lead obtaining *over-optimistic* cross validation scores.

Reading the documentation, it just says that the effect of initial shuffling just shuffles the data **at the beginning**, before splitting it into K-folds, training on the K-1 and testing on the one left out, and repeating for the number of folds **without** re-shuffling.. So, according to this, one shouldn't worry too much. Of course it the `shuffle` occurred at each iteration of training during cross validation, one would end up considering generalization error on points that were previously considered during training, committing a bad mistake, but is this the case?

How can I interpret the fact that in this case I get slightly better values when `shuffle` is `True`?